# disable php files caching for debugging

Tags: php, caching, server, zpanel

I have a vps with zpanel installed and apache2 - php - mysql.

I'm developing a small backend for a website in php, for sites ready to publish the situation is perfect, but now I need to disable the server feature that caches php files to test instantly the correct (last modified version) of my php files.
This is because while html and js files, when edited, are reloaded correctly immediately, with php I have a long wait before it updates or I have to restart the server.

I tried to open php.ini and look for "cache" and set to "1" millisecond almost all the values with no luck.
what could I try?

P.S. it's not a browser cache problem, that's a server side problem.

Comment: Which opcache are you using? Zend Optimizer? Zend Opcache? APC? Check `phpinfo()`

Comment: I have never heard of a server doing this. The only time I have ever had cache problems is when the php headers say that the page has not been updated. 

It would be helpful to see the phpinfo as suggested.

Comment: This may help too : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html

Comment: Here http://pastebin.com/iGb7dAw1 phpinfo, I will look for informations about Zend so

Answer (score 7):

Solved: inside php.ini I added a line with

```
apc.enabled=0
```

after that I restarted apache2 and now php files are updated istantly as they should

thanks for the suggestion to look into phpinfo