# How to disable the cache on server side for php file on Apache?

Tags: php, apache, caching, opcache

this question is similar to: [disable php files caching for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722592/disable-php-files-caching-for-debugging)

Currently, I try to debug a PHP website but I discover that there is some cache problem. When I update a PHP file, the update may or may not be available right now. I even deleted the index.php and the Website was still working.

This is not a browser cache problem because I use Chrome Incognito + Chrome Developer with "Disable Cache" checked + "Empty cache and Hard reload".

<s>I think the problem come from the fact that PHP were upgraded to 7.3.XX (from 5.X) and there's a OPcache module enabled by default.</s>

Is there a way to ignore this module. This website is on a shared hosting plan so I may not be able to edit config files.

**EDIT**: OPcache was not activated in the Cpanel. I also downgrade to PHP 5.6 and the problem is still here.

**New observation**: Before the PHP downgrade, I got a info.php file that print the phpinfo(). It was and is still showing 7.3 as version (cache?). I created a copy of that file and named it info2.php. This one is showing 5.6 as as PHP version. So there is still a cache somewhere.

Also, is this possible that the .htaccess file is also cached?

Answer (score 1):

If your hoster has enabled `user.ini` files you can drop an ini file in your project directory containing:

```
opcache.enable=0
```

[PHP Manual - Opcache config](https://www.php.net/manual/de/opcache.configuration.php)

Comment: Thank you for you help. But I just discovered that this module was not activated in the CPanel. I edited my question with a new observation.

Comment: Do you have [`APC`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) enabled?

Comment: Not, it is not.

Comment: After you deleted the index file did it take some time for it to not work anymore or is it still working?

Comment: It take some time for it to work. I also notice that (because I don't have a rewrite rule), it can be updated on the www URL but not on non-www URL. It is like if it's cached by URL but not on client side (I tested with cache disabled, incognito mode, hard reload, multiple browsers).

Comment: I cannot help you anymore from here, my guess is that maybe you have changed the wrong files or there is some other third party service / extension caching contents (like cloudflare)

Comment: I also guess on an extension caching contents from this host. This is the host of the client, I didn't configured it so this may be the source of the problem.